# Sound doesn't play after using my compiled .exe file on another computer

Tags: c#, monogame

My project code and all the required assets are [link to code repo](https://bitbucket.org/diliupg/gameproject-c)

All code works, compiles well and runs well on all Windows computers except the sound. The sound works only on the computer where the code is compiled on.

Comment: Please take a moment to read this- [MCVE] and edit your question accordingly

Comment: I cannot even begin to imagine which part of the code to post here. That is why the question is like this and i posted a link to all the code. This is not a simple issue.

Comment: You'll need to debug the code - make your application create a debug log, check that the audio files are in the right directory (the one that the application is trying to access), etc. We can't do that for you

Comment: Do you use any sound library that may not be present on other computers ?

Comment: Well surely you can write a simple app to play 1 sound in a manner similar to your app (and as I cant read your code cos its a link) and then test that that works or fails and then you have minimal code if it doesnt, if it works you know you got it wrong somewhere

Comment: I am new to c# coming from Python. I never even anticipated this sort of problem. The Course at Cousera did not talk about porting to other machine. I assumed that everything will work as long as the platform stays the same like with Python where I have never had any issues with Windows or Linux since 2013. I will do what BugFinder suggests and also ask around at Monogame forums.

Comment: I do not use any sound libraries other than what is provided by windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above problem was all about the DirectX redistributable which can be found [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=8109)

and [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35)

Once these were installed the game ran perfectly on all machines. It was not a code error just a matter of redistributable files.
I hope this helps others.